# Isomorphism of Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

True or False

1. Let $f:R\to S$ be a homomorphism of rings.  Then $f(1_R) = 1_S$
2. Let $f:R\to S$ be a homomorphism of rings.  Then $f(0_R) = 0_S$
3. Suppose $u$ is a unit in a ring $R.$  The $u$ cannot be a zero divisor.
4. Let $R$ be a ring.  Suppose $z$ is in the ring and is not a zero divisor. Then $z$ is a unit.
5. There is a bijection from $Z(6)$ onto $Z(2) \times Z(3)$.

If someone could help me with formatting a little I would appreciate it.  We went over isomorphisms in class.  Still not completely understanding of the concept yet.
My answers: F, T, T, F, T

Comment: The definition of ring homomorphism that I am familiar with requires condition 1, so that would be T in my book. The rest of your answers are correct.

Comment: definition the book says is f(a+b) = f(a)+f(b) and the same for multiplication.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_homomorphism

Comment: alright. any insight if I have the right idea for the rest?

Comment: for number one though my notes say that this is true if f is surjective and R is a ring with identity.  How is it proven that these conditions are met in the question?

Comment: thats why I said false because if the functions were not surjective but were still homomorphisms which can happen, this could be proven false given the right example.

Comment: I'm answering your question based on the definition I know and use. The definition used in the wikipedia article requires all rings to have an identity. If the definition of ring that is used in your class does not require them to have the identity, then the condition $f(1_R) = 1_S$ would not be part of the definition.

Comment: yeah our definition actually says that the statement in number 2 is always true

Comment: In short, different people / books use different conventions. If your book / notes says "This is the definition of a ring," and the problems you are doing are based on those definitions, you should follow that convention.

Comment: yes I completely understand

Comment: is there an example that makes 4 false? i am having trouble negating it.

Comment: Think about the ring of integers. (The integers are basically the prototype of all rings.)

Comment: im just having a hard time applying the definition of a unit and a zero divisor toward an example

Comment: So a zero-divisor is something non-zero multiplies with another non-zero to give you a 0. Are there any zero-divisors in the integers?

Comment: A unit is something that has a multiplicative inverse. Can you think of some units in the integers? (Hint: There are only two.) Note that in order for units to make sense, you need a $1$ in your ring.

Comment: I would like to guess but I really cant think of much unless it is Z(sub 4) or something like that then you could multiply two nonzeros and get 0

Comment: Right. So $Z$ has no zero-divisors. So for example, $2$ is not a zero-divisor. At the same time, $2$ is not a unit, since $2*x = 1$ does not have a solution in the integers.

Answer (score 1):

For (1), some books require a ring homomorphism to map the multiplicative identity to the multiplicative identity, so if that's the case for you, it's trivially true. If the definition doesn't require it, then the statement is false; consider $\varphi : R \to R \times R$ defined by $r \mapsto (r, 0)$.  In this case $\varphi(1_R) = (1, 0) \neq (1, 1) = 1_{R \times R}$. Moreover, if $\varphi(1_R) \neq 1_S$, then $\varphi(1_R)$ is a zero divisor.

(2) is true as $f(0_R) = f(0_R + 0_R) = f(0_R) + f(0_R)$, subtracting $f(0_R)$ from both sides yields $f(0_R) = 0_S$ as desired.

(3) is true: Suppose $u$ is a unit and suppose, by way of contradiction that $u$ is a zero divisor, then there exists $0 \neq v$ such that $uv = 0$, but notice that $u^{-1}(uv) = (u^{-1}u)v = v = 0$, contradicting the fact that $0 \neq v$. Conclude that $u$ is not a zero divisor.

(4) is false. Consider $\mathbb Z$ as the comments pointed out repeatedly. The only units are $\pm 1$ and the only zero divisor is $0$ (it has no nonzero zero divisors as it is an integral domain). For instance $2$ is not a unit and it is not a zero divisor.

(5) is true. Define $\varphi : \mathbb Z_6 \to \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_3$ by $[x]_6 \mapsto \big([x]_2, [x]_3\big)$. The first question we need to ask is: is this map well-defined? Suppose $[x]_6 = [y]_6$, then $x \equiv y \pmod 6$ which means $x - y = 6s$ for some $s \in \mathbb Z$. In particular, notice that $x - y = 2(3 \cdot s)$ which means $x \equiv y \pmod 2$ and $x - y = 3(2 \cdot s)$ which means $x \equiv y \pmod 3$. Hence we have $$\varphi\big([x]_6\big) = \big([x]_2, [x]_3\big) = \big([y]_2, [y]_3\big) = \varphi\big([y]_6\big)$$ and we can conclude that $\varphi$ is well-defined.

That it's a ring homomorphism follows from the additive and multiplicative properties of equivalence classes: $[x + y] = [x] + [y]$, $[xy] = [x][y]$.

Is $\varphi$ injective? Suppose $\varphi\big([x]_6\big) = \varphi\big([y]_6\big)$, then $x \equiv y \pmod 2$ and $x \equiv y \pmod 3$. This means that $x - y = 2s = 3t$ where $s, t \in \mathbb Z$. Notice that since $2 \nmid 3$, it must follow that $2 \mid t$ which means $t = 2v$ for some $v \in \mathbb Z$. Hence $x - y = 3t = 3 \cdot (2v) = 6v$ which means $x \equiv y \pmod 6$ and thus $[x]_6 = [y]_6$. Conclude that $\varphi$ is injective.

Is $\varphi$ surjective? Yes, notice that
\begin{align*}
[0]_6 &\mapsto \big([0]_2, [0]_3\big) \\
[1]_6 &\mapsto \big([1]_2, [1]_3\big) \\
[2]_6 &\mapsto \big([0]_2, [2]_3\big) \\
[3]_6 &\mapsto \big([1]_2, [0]_3\big) \\
[4]_6 &\mapsto \big([0]_2, [1]_3\big) \\
[5]_6 &\mapsto \big([1]_2, [2]_3\big)
\end{align*}

Conclude that $\varphi$ is a bijection between $\mathbb Z_6$ and $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_3$.